# SFSafariViewController language is not updated

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm working on a project in swift 2.0. The App is for two languages chinese and english.

I'm using the SFSafariViewController to open the url. Now the problem is when i choose the english language the url load successfully. But I convert the language to chinese then the SFSafariViewController load the same url again in english.

I have sent a new parameter with url to set the language in the browser but this do not works. Any Suggestion regarding this? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit : Code

```
    let language = (Localize.currentLanguage() != "zh-Hans" ? "en" : "zh")
 if language == "zh"{
  let externalURL = ApiURLs.webViewPath + "/?source=ios&lang=zh-CN"

  let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: externalURL)!)

  self.presentViewController(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
  else
{
   let externalURL = ApiURLs.webViewPath + "/?source=ios&lang=en-US"

   let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: externalURL)!)

   self.presentViewController(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I have added the code, Please check this.

Comment: I haveChecked the url in chrome it is open successfully in chines language but not in SFSafariViewController. The url is :https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus?/&lang=zh-CN

Comment: try printing `language` after the `let language = ...` line to see what value are you getting

Comment: @Malik, I have checked that. In dubugging i 'm getting "zh"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're creating a wrong url

Please make sure that your `ApiURLs.webViewPath` is `https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus` and `externalURL` is as below

```
let externalURL = ApiURLs.webViewPath + "?source=ios&lang=zh-CN"
```

If you print your `externalURL` then it should look like this

```
https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus?source=ios&lang=zh-CN
```

I've tested the below code and it was working fine for me, below code is for swift4 but the importing thing is the url

```
if language == "zh" {
  let externalURL = "https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus?source=ios&lang=zh-CN"
  let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: externalURL)! as URL)
  self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else {
  let externalURL = "https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus?source=ios&lang=en-US"
  let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: externalURL)! as URL)
  self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried to implement the above code in my app. My control is goes into the if statement. But the browser still shows the content in the english language.

Comment: Gurmeet I don't know what is happening at your side, can you hard code the whole url `https://www.iceangelid.net/#/aboutus?source=ios&lang=zh-CN` both in if and else statement and see what's happening

Comment: I have paste the above code and still getting the same issue.